# AlertDailogBox in android,saving file

Tags: android, file, android-alertdialog

In my application on clicking on button i'm showing alert dailog box to get file name.and getting name from user for a file.and saving it.
but what is happening is, after clicking on button alert dailog box is gets infront of screen and before that its try to save file.but its trying to save file befor user enters the name for file thats why file name  is null in saving file.how to call use alert box so that i can get name from user and then save the file using that name.plase help me.

```
 public void savebitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    str++;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Work.this);
    alert.setMessage("File name :");
    input = new EditText(Work.this);
    input.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,50));
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            NameValue = input.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("   file name.---"+NameValue);
        }

    });
    alert.show();
    System.out.println("file is..."+NameValue);

    try
    {
        System.out.println("in bitmap save...");
        File fn=new File("/sdcard/"+" filename4"+".png");
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(fn);
        System.out.println(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"+out);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in   "+fn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will to move all file saving code inside onClick event of Button or wrap all code inside a method and then call it on Button click as :

```
public void savebitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
      //....your code here
        alert.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    NameValue = input.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("   file name.---"+NameValue);

                    // put your code here to save file on Ok button click
                   saveFileOnSdCard(NameValue);
                }

            });
            alert.show();
    }

    private void saveFileOnSdCard(String str_filename){
      // move yor file saving code here..
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take input first then when user press OK on that you need to create file. So you need to write code in side `onClick`.

Try this,

```
public void savebitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    str++;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Work.this);
    alert.setMessage("File name :");
    input = new EditText(Work.this);
    input.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,50));
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            NameValue = input.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("   file name.---"+NameValue);
            try
            {
                System.out.println("in bitmap save...");
                File fn=new File("/sdcard/"+" filename4"+".png");
                FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(fn);
                System.out.println(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"+out);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90,out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();   

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }
        }

    });
    alert.show();
    System.out.println("file is..."+NameValue);


}
```